# Converting this complex number to polar form?

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

Given $ z = -1 - i$
,I converted it to polar form, resulting  r =$\sqrt  2$.

And  $\theta = \tan^{-1} (\frac{-1}{-1}$) = 0.785 rads, which seems incorrect with the solutions of my instructor I don't understand why...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
In which quadrant of the plane does that point reside?

Comment: 3rd, therefore i'd subtract the result from $\pi$

Comment: @XCIX: Why? What are the reasonable values for $\theta$ in the 3rd quadrant?

Comment: @Henrik the result is -2.356, that is a possible value(and turned to be correct with the solution)

Comment: @Workaholic drew it, substracted

Comment: You really should express those angles as multipla of $\pi$ (but that of course requires that you know those values of $\sin$/$\cos$/$\tan$), those numbers mean nothing to me (but I can do the calculations needed to compare).

Answer (score 0):

$-1-i$ is in the 3rd quarant, reasonable values for $\theta$ are between $\pi$ and $\frac32\pi$ (or $-\pi$ and $-\frac\pi2$ if you prefer values between $-\pi$ and $\pi$). $\tan^{-1}$ gives values between $-\frac\pi2$ and $\frac\pi2$, so you need to correct it by either adding or subtracting $\pi$.